# Trying to remove all references from old domain in wordpress site after migration to new domain

Tags: wp-cli

I have moved a website from old domain to new domain and have used the following WP CLI command

```
$ wp search-replace --skip-columns=guid "olddomainname.com" "newdomainname.com"
```

which seemed to replace a lot of search strings.
However when I use WPALLImport to import new records with images they are cross linked to the old domain.
I have even tried:

```
$ find . -name '*.php' -exec grep -H -n -i -F "olddomain.com"
```

but I do not get anything useful except for a line in wp-config.php
//define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://olddomain.com/' );
which I have already commented out.

What can I try next?

Comment: Why skip the `guid` column? Are you running `wp search-replace` after the WP All Import import?

Comment: No, It has been my "go to" tool after changing a wordpress website main domain.  That is the only time I use it.

Comment: Try running `wp search-replace` after the import, and include the `guid` column.